# How to add the Selected attribute to a Select Option in Fable?

Tags: html, f#, fable-f#

I have a select tag on my page:

```
open Fable.Helpers.React
open Fable.Helpers.React.Props

select [] 
       [
            option [ Value "a" ] [ str "a" ]
            option [ Value "b" ] [ str "b" ]
            option [ Value "c" ] [ str "c" ]
       ]
```

Which transpiles to:

```
<select>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

Now, let's say I want "b" to have the [selected](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp) attribute. I try:

```
option [ Value "b"; Selected true ] [ str "b" ]
```

And nothing changes in HTML. Whereas if I e.g. try:

```
option [ Value "b"; Disabled true ] [ str "b" ]
```

HTML changes accordingly:

```
<option value="b" disabled="">b</option>
```

So what to do with the "selected" attribute? I need to get:

```
<option value="b" selected="">b</option>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as proposed by @Foole you need to use `Value` in order set the selected item.

Here is a small code allowing you to understand how to use it and hook it up in an Elmish program:

```
type Model =
    { Selected : string }

type Msg =
    | ChangeValue of string

let init () = { Selected = "option-2" }, Cmd.none

let update (msg:Msg) (model:Model) =
    match msg with
    | ChangeValue newValue ->
        { Selected = newValue }, Cmd.none

let renderItem (key : string) (name : string) =
    option [ Value key ]
        [ str name ]

let view model dispatch =
    select [ // Set the selected key
             Value model.Selected
             // Listen to `OnChange` event to update the `Model`
             OnChange (fun ev ->
                ChangeValue ev.target?value
                |> dispatch
             ) ]
        [ renderItem "option-1" "Apple"
          renderItem "option-2" "Pear"
          renderItem "option-3" "Orange" ]
```

In the code proposed by @Foole, you cannot change the choice because `Value "b"` is static and you don't update it.

Comment: A much more helpful answer. This approach fixed the problem, awesome!

Comment: When using Feliz, Fable.Browser.Dom NuGet package is required for ev (of type Browser.Types.Event).

Answer (score 0):

Add it as the value on the "select" element:

```
   select [ Value "b" ] [
        option [ Value "a" ] [ str "a" ]
        option [ Value "b" ] [ str "b" ]
        option [ Value "c" ] [ str "c" ]
   ]
```

Comment: Hmm, no, looks like it does not change the HTML. Strangely, when the web page loads, it has "b" selected but now I cannot change the choice in the select - it resets to this value immediately.

Comment: That is how react works.  I would suggest either learning more about react, or using a different view engine.